# Lat-Long processing in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB for storing the tweets of twitter using twitter APIs and php code.
How to get the location of tweets which are stored in MongoDB with respect to lattitude and longitude?

Comment: did you have a look at the geolocation API?

Comment: No i dont have any idea regarding it.How can I use it in my php code for getting lat and long?

Comment: I have never used twitter API..if you could give a sample data from it I could give you the code

Comment: which data you want??I mean the code which i wrote or any other thing ?

Comment: The data that the twitter API returns

Comment: [{ "tweet":"@SiriusXMHits1 @LittleMixOffic #LittleMixOnHits1 ! Have u ever tasted arabic food? Love from lebanon\u2665\u2665\u2665\u2665 30" },{ "tweet":"@fandomcrazyness i know right?!?!?!?!?!?!?! IT LOOKS TERRIFYING YET I CANT WAIT TO BE SCARED SHITLESS. Also, food yum" }]

Comment: Are all the entries similar to this one? there are no location entries in this document..How can you possibly access them?

Comment: yes,all are similar.that;s y i m also confused.

Answer (score 1):

According to Twitter's documentation on [tweet fields](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets), the `coordinates` field is a nullable [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) object. Obviously, not all tweets will have coordinate data, so you'll have to account for that possibility.

Conveniently, the GeoJSON format is what MongoDB 2.4+ uses for its [2dsphere geospatial indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/). If you're storing the tweet as it comes from Twitter, you should be able to create such an index on the `coordinates` field and have MongoDB track it accordingly. If the `coordinates` field is `null` or not a GeoJSON object for whatever reason, I would simply delete the field from the document before storage, since MongoDB will complain if you attempt to index an invalid geospatial value.

In earlier versions of MongoDB, [2d indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2d/) were used, where values were either a tuple of longitude and latitude values (in that order), or an object with longitude and latitude as the only properties (in that order). I would definitely recommend using the newer 2dsphere indexes if possible.

A helpful chart of all of MongoDB's geospatial query operators can be found on [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-geospatial/). This includes mention of which queries support 2dsphere and legacy 2d indexes.

Two helpful blog posts introducing 2dsphere indexes are:

- [New Geo Features in MongoDB 2.4](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/50984169045/new-geo-features-in-mongodb-2-4)
- [2dsphere, GeoJSON, and Doctrine MongoDB](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/53751481851/2dsphere-geojson-and-doctrine-mongodb)

The latter post is my own, and talks about using a [GeoJSON PHP library](https://github.com/jmikola/geojson) I wrote along with [Doctrine MongoDB](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb). Regardless of whether you'd like to explore using Doctrine, the GeoJSON library may be helpful for validating the `coordinates` fields before storing them in MongoDB.