# Add a new field point type filed to a collection with value of an existing field

Tags: mongodb, spatial

I have a huge mongodb collection with 6 million records. I have two fields (latitude, longitude), and I would like to add a third field to the collection with the type of point (spatial). How to do this in command line or PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you'd like to add a new field (with the same value) to all documents in a collection, that can be done easily with an [`update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update) operation. Consider the following shell example:

```
db.collection.update(
  {},
  { $set: { type: "spatial" }},
  { multi: true }
);
```

This would set the `type` field to "spatial" for all documents matching empty criteria `{}` (i.e. everything), and the `multi` option allows the update to modify multiple documents instead of just the first document matched (default behavior).

If you only wanted to set the `type` field where it doesn't already exist, you could tweak the criteria like so:

```
db.collection.update(
  { type: { $exists: false }},
  { $set: { type: "spatial" }},
  { multi: true }
);
```

Since you're storing geospatial data, you may want to have a look at MongoDB's [2dsphere indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/). This would allow you to store and index well-formed [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org) objects in your document. See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21740499/162228) from a related question for more introductory information on the subject.